# How do I "accept" an answer?

Tags: discussion

I was told my accept rate is awful, but I can't find anything to tell me how to do that?

Comment: Although [the system no longer shows users' accept rates, for good reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951), this is still a useful meta question. The purpose of accepting an answer isn't--and wasn't ever (or shouldn't ever have been)--to increase one's accept rate. Instead, the purpose is to show that a particular answer solved the asker's problem or answered their question. Here and on other SE sites, the community as a whole determines the displayed *score* of a post. Accepting is an important feature to show that an answer is endorsed by the person who actually asked the question

Answer (score 24):

You can accept an answer by clicking the check-mark next to it. Once you've accepted it, it'll show in green. You can change your choice at any time.

[image]

If you decide to accept your own answer (which is totally fine by the way), you will have to wait two days after asking the question. Otherwise, you can do it when ever you like.

The answer you accept should be the one that helped *you* the most.

Comment: I don't see the checkmark! Has this feature been changed?

Answer (score 5):

See also:

- [How to improve my accept rate?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1006/how-to-improve-my-accept-rate)

Answer (score 1):

Just click the "accept answer" button next to the answer that answers your question.

Comment: If I saw an "accept answer" button I would have clicked on it! (That was the first thing I looked for!!!)

Comment: You could have told me it was the unobtrusive checkmark located near the answer!

Comment: It's an overly obtrusive check mark.