# Are answers more likely to be accepted on superuser than on askubuntu?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I'm taking action in the stackexchange network for half a year now and experienced that many of my answers got accepted on superuser.com whereas all of my answers on askubuntu weren't accepted, even if the user asking the question posted a comment to thank me for my answer.

The problem of users not accepting answers is already discussed in "[Encouraging (new) users to accept answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2869/encouraging-new-users-to-accept-answers)", but this didn't help me with my problem that my answers are very more likely to be accepted on superuser. I find this very discouraging and I will therefore more likely answer questions on superuser than on askubuntu.

What I want to know is if you are experiencing the same problem and if anyone can tell me what the reasons for that are and what can be done to change this.

Comment: There is an active discussion on this here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6408/how-to-handle-users-that-ask-a-question-and-never-come-back

Comment: This isn't only about users who don't come back. And my question is rather about the difference between superuser and askubuntu and what can be done on a global scale, not what I can do myself.

Comment: Since this is a *cross-site* question, it might be better posted on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). I'm not saying we should immediately treat it as off-topic here...but we may want to migrate it there if it doesn't get any answers here for a while.

Comment: Sounds good. I didn't even now that MSO exists.

Comment: I have made some feature requests but they where hated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185528/222006 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187177/222006

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing to be done to change it.  Superuser rep+accept is just easier to get than AU rep+accept.  If you think it's hard here, try grinding out some rep on serverfault.

Comment: Very true answer.